# Windows C++ 32-bit DLL Strange Behavior in Timer Thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, dll, timer, callback

I am just learning how to right a DLL.  This project will ultimately be a plugin for music players and is based on Winamp 5.X.

I want to create a window to show information about the playing song that updates periodically, but it's not a "visualization" plugin which is by definition called back repeatedly by the main program.  I need a timer, and another source suggested to use CreateTimerQueueTimer() which starts a separate thread to receive the timeout event instead of infinite looping and checking window messages for stop condition.  I have no knowledge of multithreading architecture (if any) in the main program so I similarly don't want to just loop through a "sleep" interval then refreshing output.

1. The approach seems to work.  It is based on a callback function:

```
char message[12] = "Hallo World";

VOID CALLBACK TimerCallback(PVOID lpParameter, BOOLEAN reserved)
{
    message[1] += 1;
    MessageBoxA(NULL, message, "Dummy", MB_OK);
}
```

The 1st popup shows "Hallo World", the 2nd "Hbllo World" on so on.

The mystery is that when I switch the two lines of code in the CALLBACK, all the popups (which are created every 10 seconds) show "Hallo World".  I don't understand why that is happening, and I don't think I should try to move on to more complex tasks until I get what's going on here.

As always, any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I kind of figured this out.  Thought it might help someone else to leave the post up.

In previous testing, I was not closing the popup MessageBox before a new one was generated.  On further testing, when I close the boxes as they appear, both behaviors increment as expected.

Still, if anyone wants to comment I'm not completely at ease with my understanding of whats happening.

Comment: What happens is this: ``MessageBoxA()`` returns only after the box has been closed by the user. So, in the case where you switch the two lines of code, this happens: as long as the message boxes remain open, ``message[1] += 1;`` never gets executed.